# How can I use the useQuery hook to populate state in other hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, react-hooks

I have been dealing with a few hook-related issues recently as I have been implementing hooks into a project of mine.  I keep getting the error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render."

It seems that the only way I can get my code to work is by putting the useQuery hook after all of the other hooks.  This is a problem however as I want to populate some values of state with values from data on the query.

```
// code that doesn't error, but am not able to initialize state with query values

const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

const updateLink = useMutation(LINK_UPDATE_MUTATION, {
  variables: {
    id: props.id,
    url
  }
})

const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(LINK_QUERY, {
  variables: {
    id: props.id
  }
})

if (loading) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}
if (error) {
  return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>
}
```

vs

```
// code that errors with 'Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.'

const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(LINK_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      id: props.id
    }
  })

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  if (error) {
    return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>
  }

const updateLink = useMutation(LINK_UPDATE_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
      id: props.id,
      url
    }
  })

const [url, setUrl] = useState(data.link.url)
```

I would expect that the useQuery hook could be used in a way to initialize other values with its query data.

If this isn't enough code or more explanation is needed just let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you need to do is to update the state when the first hook results in a response. To do that you can make use of `useEffect` hook. You need to render all hooks at the top of your functional component.

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

const updateLink = useMutation(LINK_UPDATE_MUTATION, {
  variables: {
    id: props.id,
    url
  }
})

const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(LINK_QUERY, {
  variables: {
    id: props.id
  }
})

useEffect(() => {
  if(data && data.link) {
    setUrl(data.link.url);
  }
}, [data])

if (loading) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}
if (error) {
  return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I now get the error 'Cannot read property 'url' of undefined' after adding the useEffect hook.  I believe this error indicates that the data from the database did not come back before --> `useEffect(() => {
    setUrl(data.link.url)
  }, [data.link.url])`  How should I go about delaying the useEffect hook until the data comes back from the database?  The `if (loading)` takes care of that, but if I move the useEffect hook below that I continue to get the same error as before.

Comment: useEffect runs on the initial render as well. Also you must pass `data` as the key instead of `data.link.url` to useEffect dependency array and then check for data value in the effect. I updated my answer to reflect the change

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri what happens when `data` is an array or object? since the dependency array only does shallow comparisons, that useEffect will be called as often as the component rerenders since the referenced value changes

Comment: @Luminusss, in such cases you need to make sure that data reference changes only while updating its state, since inthe above case useQuery won't return you a new reference everytime it runs, it would work seemlessly